# build FCM http batch request

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to use a Firebase cloud messaging to send notifications to multiple tokens, I plan on building an HTTP batch request for gcp's batch endpoint, but I am having some difficulties finding the right tools that will help me do so.
I thought about using the SDK but I only need the messaging features.
The HTTP batch request is as follows:

```
--subrequest_boundary
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Authorization: Bearer ya29.ElqKBGN2Ri_Uz...HnS_uNreA

POST /v1/projects/myproject-b5ae1/messages:send
Content-Type: application/json
accept: application/json

{
 "message":{
    "token":"bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
    "notification":{
      "title":"FCM Message",
      "body":"This is an FCM notification message!"
    }
 }
}

...

--subrequest_boundary
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Authorization: Bearer ya29.ElqKBGN2Ri_Uz...HnS_uNreA

POST /v1/projects/myproject-b5ae1/messages:send
Content-Type: application/json
accept: application/json

{
 "message":{
    "token":"cR1rjyj4_Kc:APA91bGusqbypSuMdsh7jSNrW4nzsM...",
    "notification":{
      "title":"FCM Message",
      "body":"This is an FCM notification message!"
    }
 }
}
--subrequest_boundary--
```

To be sent as a file as follows:

```
curl --data-binary @batch_request.txt -H 'Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="subrequest_boundary"' https://fcm.googleapis.com/batch
```

edit: We want to build an http request with the content above, and send it in a multipart file to https://fcm.googleapis.com/batch

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.